# javascript versus jQuery: highlighting some text, at the same time as, changing visibility of other text

Tags: javascript, jquery

This javascript code from RoToRa does what I want:
http://jsbin.com/ayoqem/7/edit#javascript,html,live 
What jQuery code will do the same task? Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you don't need to use jQuery then the javascript you have already will do just fine. But if you are using jQuery then you can accomplish the same task with just 3 lines of code.

http://jsfiddle.net/RWzQT/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".qa input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent('div').toggleClass('show_answer');
    });
});​
```

Note, that I also removed your inline javascript (`onclick="hlt_showhide(this)"`) from the HTML.

Comment: Thanks very much. It really helped that you added a jsfiddle. I found out how to change visibility http://jsfiddle.net/wzMM4/26/ but I couldn't see how to both change visibility and add highlights at the same time.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problems, you could also achieve what you have above with code like this. http://jsfiddle.net/wzMM4/44/ . Keeps it short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need jQuery, don't use it. jQuery is built on top of JavaScript.. so if you already have code in pure-JS, why do you want it in jQuery??

The jQuery equivalent of that will be very similar in terms of line by line flow, only it'll use jQuery's `.parent()` to select the parent element and `.addClass()` & `.removeClass()` to do those actions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function hlt_showhide(checkbox) {
   $checkbox = $(checked); // just to cache it really!      
   var qaDiv = $checkbox.parent().parent();  
   if ($checkbox.attr('checked'))  {
       qaDiv.addClass("show_answer");
   } else {
      qaDiv.removeClass("show_answer");
   }
}
```

but frankly I dont see the point of using jQuery here! JS does the trick.